# FileNotFoundError("No such file: '%s'" % fn) FileNotFoundError: No such file: (Mask_RCNN)

Tags: python, machine-learning, anaconda, nvidia

### Trying to run mask_rcnn's sample program color splash and am getting this error:

I am running the mrcnn model on anaconda in my environment ***masknet***  with the following packages installed.
I have  followed the instructions given in the readme file which is in https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/tree/master/samples/balloon or [you could check the medium article which explains the tutorial](https://engineering.matterport.com/splash-of-color-instance-segmentation-with-mask-r-cnn-and-tensorflow-7c761e238b46)

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_tflow_select             2.1.0                       gpu
absl-py                   0.9.0                    py37_0    conda-forge
astor                     0.7.1                      py_0    conda-forge
blas                      1.0                         mkl
ca-certificates           2019.11.28           hecc5488_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2019.11.28               py37_0    conda-forge
cloudpickle               1.2.2                      py_1    conda-forge
cudatoolkit               10.0.130                      0    anaconda
cudnn                     7.6.5                cuda10.0_0
cycler                    0.10.0                     py_2    conda-forge
cytoolz                   0.10.1           py37hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
dask-core                 2.10.1                     py_0    conda-forge
decorator                 4.4.1                      py_0    conda-forge
freetype                  2.10.0               h563cfd7_1    conda-forge
gast                      0.2.2                      py_0    conda-forge
google-pasta              0.1.8                      py_0    conda-forge
grpcio                    1.23.0           py37h3db2c7e_0    conda-forge
h5py                      2.10.0          nompi_py37h422b98e_102    conda-forge
hdf5                      1.10.5          nompi_ha405e13_1104    conda-forge
icc_rt                    2019.0.0             h0cc432a_1
imageio                   2.6.1                    py37_0    conda-forge
intel-openmp              2020.0                      166
jpeg                      9c                hfa6e2cd_1001    conda-forge
keras                     2.2.4                    py37_1    conda-forge
keras-applications        1.0.8                      py_1    conda-forge
keras-base                2.2.4                    py37_0
keras-gpu                 2.2.4                         0
keras-preprocessing       1.1.0                      py_0    conda-forge
kiwisolver                1.1.0            py37he980bc4_0    conda-forge
libblas                   3.8.0                    14_mkl    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.8.0                    14_mkl    conda-forge
libgpuarray               0.7.6             hfa6e2cd_1003    conda-forge
liblapack                 3.8.0                    14_mkl    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.37               h7602738_0    conda-forge
libprotobuf               3.11.3               h1a1b453_0    conda-forge
libtiff                   4.1.0                h21b02b4_3    conda-forge
lz4-c                     1.8.3             he025d50_1001    conda-forge
m2w64-gcc-libgfortran     5.3.0                         6
m2w64-gcc-libs            5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gcc-libs-core       5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gmp                 6.1.0                         2
m2w64-libwinpthread-git   5.0.0.4634.697f757               2
mako                      1.1.0                      py_0    conda-forge
markdown                  3.1.1                      py_0    conda-forge
markupsafe                1.1.1            py37hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
matplotlib-base           3.1.3            py37h2981e6d_0    conda-forge
mkl                       2019.4                      245
mkl-service               2.3.0            py37hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
msys2-conda-epoch         20160418                      1
networkx                  2.4                        py_0    conda-forge
numpy                     1.18.1           py37hc71023c_0    conda-forge
olefile                   0.46                       py_0    conda-forge
openssl                   1.1.1d               hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
opt_einsum                3.1.0                      py_0    conda-forge
pillow                    7.0.0            py37h9ea1dd6_0    conda-forge
pip                       20.0.2                     py_2    conda-forge
protobuf                  3.11.3           py37he025d50_0    conda-forge
pygpu                     0.7.6           py37hc8d92b1_1000    conda-forge
pyparsing                 2.4.6                      py_0    conda-forge
pyreadline                2.1                   py37_1001    conda-forge
python                    3.7.6                h5b45d93_2    conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.8.1                      py_0    conda-forge
pywavelets                1.1.1            py37hc8d92b1_0    conda-forge
pyyaml                    5.3              py37hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
scikit-image              0.16.2           py37he350917_0    conda-forge
scipy                     1.4.1            py37h9439919_0
setuptools                45.1.0                   py37_0    conda-forge
six                       1.14.0                   py37_0    conda-forge
sqlite                    3.30.1               hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
tensorboard               1.14.0                   py37_0    conda-forge
tensorflow                1.14.0          gpu_py37h5512b17_0
tensorflow-base           1.14.0          gpu_py37h55fc52a_0
tensorflow-estimator      1.14.0           py37h5ca1d4c_0    conda-forge
tensorflow-gpu            1.14.0               h0d30ee6_0
termcolor                 1.1.0                      py_2    conda-forge
theano                    1.0.4           py37h6538335_1001    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.10               hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
toolz                     0.10.0                     py_0    conda-forge
tornado                   6.0.3            py37hfa6e2cd_2    conda-forge
vc                        14.1                 h0510ff6_4
vs2015_runtime            14.16.27012          hf0eaf9b_1
vs2015_win-64             14.0.25420          h55c1224_11
werkzeug                  0.16.1                     py_0    conda-forge
wheel                     0.34.2                     py_1    conda-forge
wincertstore              0.2                   py37_1003    conda-forge
wrapt                     1.11.2           py37hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.4             h2fa13f4_1001    conda-forge
yaml                      0.2.2                hfa6e2cd_1    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.11            h2fa13f4_1006    conda-forge
zstd                      1.4.4                hd8a0e53_1    conda-forge
```

[This the link to the Mask_RCNN Github repo](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/tree/master/samples/balloon)

```
(masknet) D:\Projects\Aidc\Mask_RCNN>python balloon.py splash --weights=D:\Projects\Aidc\Mask_RCNN\mask_rcnn_balloon.h5 --image=images.forbes.com_marshallshepherd_files_2018_05_img_launching_sonde_hilo_3
        C:\Users\jarvis\Anaconda3\envs\masknet\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:516: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
      _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
    C:\Users\jarvis\Anaconda3\envs\masknet\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:517: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
      _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
    C:\Users\jarvis\Anaconda3\envs\masknet\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:518: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
      _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
    C:\Users\jarvis\Anaconda3\envs\masknet\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:519: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
      _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
    C:\Users\jarvis\Anaconda3\envs\masknet\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:520: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
      _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
    C:\Users\jarvis\Anaconda3\envs\masknet\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:525: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
      np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
    C:\Users\jarvis\Anaconda3\envs\masknet\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:541: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
      _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
    C:\Users\jarvis\Anaconda3\envs\masknet\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:542: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
      _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
    C:\Users\jarvis\Anaconda3\envs\masknet\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:543: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
      _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
    C:\Users\jarvis\Anaconda3\envs\masknet\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:544: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
      _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
    C:\Users\jarvis\Anaconda3\envs\masknet\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:545: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
      _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
    C:\Users\jarvis\Anaconda3\envs\masknet\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:550: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
      np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
    Using TensorFlow backend.
    WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\jarvis\Anaconda3\envs\masknet\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\compat\v2_compat.py:61: disable_resource_variables (from tensorflow.python.ops.variable_scope) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
    Instructions for updating:
    non-resource variables are not supported in the long term
    Weights:  D:\Projects\Aidc\Mask_RCNN\mask_rcnn_balloon.h5
    Dataset:  None
    Logs:  D:\Projects\logs

Configurations:
BACKBONE                       resnet101
BACKBONE_STRIDES               [4, 8, 16, 32, 64]
BATCH_SIZE                     1
BBOX_STD_DEV                   [0.1 0.1 0.2 0.2]
COMPUTE_BACKBONE_SHAPE         None
DETECTION_MAX_INSTANCES        100
DETECTION_MIN_CONFIDENCE       0.9
DETECTION_NMS_THRESHOLD        0.3
FPN_CLASSIF_FC_LAYERS_SIZE     1024
GPU_COUNT                      1
GRADIENT_CLIP_NORM             5.0
IMAGES_PER_GPU                 1
IMAGE_CHANNEL_COUNT            3
IMAGE_MAX_DIM                  1024
IMAGE_META_SIZE                14
IMAGE_MIN_DIM                  800
IMAGE_MIN_SCALE                0
IMAGE_RESIZE_MODE              square
IMAGE_SHAPE                    [1024 1024    3]
LEARNING_MOMENTUM              0.9
LEARNING_RATE                  0.001
LOSS_WEIGHTS                   {'rpn_class_loss': 1.0, 'rpn_bbox_loss': 1.0, 'mrcnn_class_loss': 1.0, 'mrcnn_bbox_loss': 1.0, 'mrcnn_mask_loss': 1.0}
MASK_POOL_SIZE                 14
MASK_SHAPE                     [28, 28]
MAX_GT_INSTANCES               100
MEAN_PIXEL                     [123.7 116.8 103.9]
MINI_MASK_SHAPE                (56, 56)
NAME                           balloon
NUM_CLASSES                    2
POOL_SIZE                      7
POST_NMS_ROIS_INFERENCE        1000
POST_NMS_ROIS_TRAINING         2000
PRE_NMS_LIMIT                  6000
ROI_POSITIVE_RATIO             0.33
RPN_ANCHOR_RATIOS              [0.5, 1, 2]
RPN_ANCHOR_SCALES              (32, 64, 128, 256, 512)
RPN_ANCHOR_STRIDE              1
RPN_BBOX_STD_DEV               [0.1 0.1 0.2 0.2]
RPN_NMS_THRESHOLD              0.7
RPN_TRAIN_ANCHORS_PER_IMAGE    256
STEPS_PER_EPOCH                100
TOP_DOWN_PYRAMID_SIZE          256
TRAIN_BN                       False
TRAIN_ROIS_PER_IMAGE           200
USE_MINI_MASK                  True
USE_RPN_ROIS                   True
VALIDATION_STEPS               50
WEIGHT_DECAY                   0.0001


WARNING:tensorflow:From D:\Projects\Aidc\Mask_RCNN\mrcnn\model.py:341: The name tf.log is deprecated. Please use tf.math.log instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From D:\Projects\Aidc\Mask_RCNN\mrcnn\model.py:399: add_dispatch_support.<locals>.wrapper (from tensorflow.python.ops.array_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.where in 2.0, which has the same broadcast rule as np.where
WARNING:tensorflow:From D:\Projects\Aidc\Mask_RCNN\mrcnn\model.py:423: calling crop_and_resize_v1 (from tensorflow.python.ops.image_ops_impl) with box_ind is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
box_ind is deprecated, use box_indices instead
WARNING:tensorflow:From D:\Projects\Aidc\Mask_RCNN\mrcnn\model.py:720: The name tf.sets.set_intersection is deprecated. Please use tf.sets.intersection instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From D:\Projects\Aidc\Mask_RCNN\mrcnn\model.py:722: The name tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense is deprecated. Please use tf.sparse.to_dense instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From D:\Projects\Aidc\Mask_RCNN\mrcnn\model.py:772: to_float (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.cast` instead.
Loading weights  D:\Projects\Aidc\Mask_RCNN\mask_rcnn_balloon.h5
2020-02-09 23:48:46.212184: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2
2020-02-09 23:48:46.218753: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2020-02-09 23:48:46.671920: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1640] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce 940MX major: 5 minor: 0 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.189
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
2020-02-09 23:48:46.678436: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dlopen_checker_stub.cc:25] GPU libraries are statically linked, skip dlopen check.
2020-02-09 23:48:46.685177: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1763] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-02-09 23:48:47.849866: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1181] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-02-09 23:48:47.854705: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1187]      0
2020-02-09 23:48:47.860509: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1200] 0:   N
2020-02-09 23:48:47.865251: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1326] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 1391 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce 940MX, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 5.0)
Running on images.forbes.com_marshallshepherd_files_2018_05_img_launching_sonde_hilo_3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "balloon.py", line 367, in <module>
    video_path=args.video)
  File "balloon.py", line 230, in detect_and_color_splash
    image = skimage.io.imread(args.image)
  File "C:\Users\jarvis\Anaconda3\envs\masknet\lib\site-packages\skimage\io\_io.py", line 48, in imread
    img = call_plugin('imread', fname, plugin=plugin, **plugin_args)
  File "C:\Users\jarvis\Anaconda3\envs\masknet\lib\site-packages\skimage\io\manage_plugins.py", line 210, in call_plugin
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jarvis\Anaconda3\envs\masknet\lib\site-packages\skimage\io\_plugins\imageio_plugin.py", line 10, in imread
    return np.asarray(imageio_imread(*args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\jarvis\Anaconda3\envs\masknet\lib\site-packages\imageio\core\functions.py", line 264, in imread
    reader = read(uri, format, "i", **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jarvis\Anaconda3\envs\masknet\lib\site-packages\imageio\core\functions.py", line 173, in get_reader
    request = Request(uri, "r" + mode, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jarvis\Anaconda3\envs\masknet\lib\site-packages\imageio\core\request.py", line 126, in __init__
    self._parse_uri(uri)
  File "C:\Users\jarvis\Anaconda3\envs\masknet\lib\site-packages\imageio\core\request.py", line 278, in _parse_uri
    raise FileNotFoundError("No such file: '%s'" % fn)
FileNotFoundError: No such file: 'D:\Projects\Aidc\Mask_RCNN\images.forbes.com_marshallshepherd_files_2018_05_img_launching_sonde_hilo_3'
```

I have checked and the image file is the Mask_RCNN folder, I had also changed the image just to check if it is some glitch but the effect is the same.

Answer (score 0):

actually a friend suggested the answer

```
D:\Projects\Aidc\Mask_RCNN>python balloon.py splash --weights=D:\Projects\Aidc\Mask_RCNN\mask_rcnn_balloon.h5 --image=images.forbes.com_marshallshepherd_files_2018_05_img_launching_sonde_hilo_3
```

just add a .jpg/.png extension according to the file name and also make sure to put the location in single quotes the code should be like

```
D:\Projects\Aidc\Mask_RCNN>python balloon.py splash --weights=D:\Projects\Aidc\Mask_RCNN\mask_rcnn_balloon.h5 --image='images.forbes.com_marshallshepherd_files_2018_05_img_launching_sonde_hilo_3.jpg'
```